# How to read a certain line & a few lines after in Java

Tags: java

Edit: Ok so I'm looking to find a specific line and then print a few lines (4) after the found line. This is what i have right now, but getting a lot of errors (mostly not having the FileNotFoundException established, but its there so I have no idea whats going on) and an error saying I need a ; in the 'for' loops. Help please?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Animals {

String line;
int i = 0;

BufferedReader animals = new BufferedReader(new FileReader 
    ("‪//Documents//animals.txt"));

string animalChoices () {
    string animalChoice = while ((line = animals.readLine()) != null)) {
        for (i = 0, i < 4, i++) {
         System.out.print(line);
    }
}
}

string displayAnimals () {
  string displayAnimal = while ((line = animals.readLine()) != null) {
        for (i=0, i<4, i++) {
            if (line.contains("*****")) {
                string alertLine = line.replace("*****", "ALERT!!! ");
                system.out.println(alertLine);
            }
            else if {
                system.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

An example source file:

```
monkey - jean
detail 1
detail 2
detail 3
detail 4

marmaset - rick
detail 1
detail 2
detail 3
*****detail 4
```

and an expected output if user input was marmaset:

```
marmaset - rick
detail 1
detail 2
detail 3
ALERT: detail 4
```

Comment: Have you learned how to use scanner yet?

Comment: yes, i have attached some code this time.

Comment: Why is everything in lowercase? You do know that **1.** Java is case-sensitive, and **2.** Java classes **all** start with an upper-case letter, e.g. `String`, `System`. **3.** `string displayAnimal = while ...` this is just wrong. Please have a look at how to do correct variable assignments and loops.

Comment: Better. But for the file path, use the absolute path (file path all the way to drive letter) until everything else is working. (the relative path starts at the .class file being ran)

Comment: I fixed the capital letters (still received errors in those lines so I was playing around with it). i do have the file name exact in the path, just took out the 'C://' and other parts to that.

Comment: You should use only single slashes. You probably meant to *escape* them, but that is done with a backslash \\ . Your correct path should look like `C:/Users/<username>/Documents/animals.txt`

Answer (score -1):

See if this works for you...

I created a file with the following:

```
This is a line 123
This is a line 456
This is a line 789
This is a line 012

This is a line 345

This is a line 678

This is a line 901

This is a line 234
This is a line 567
```

Here's how I search using your criteria:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CustomFileReader {

/**
 * Grab a line from a file containing a pattern, and a number of "non-zero"
 * lines after it.  Return array of Strings as the result. 
 * @param file File to search
 * @param containsThis text string first line must have...
 * @param linesToGrab # of lines to grab total.
 * @return null if file doesn't exist or the string pattern wasn't found.
 */
public static String[] getLines(File file, String containsThis,int linesToGrab)
{
    if(!file.exists()){
        System.err.println("File doesn't exist...");
        return null;
    }

    int linesGrabbed = 0;
    String[] result = new String[linesToGrab];
    boolean lookingForPattern = true;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
        {
            if(lookingForPattern){
                if(line.contains(containsThis)){
                    result[linesGrabbed++] = line;
                    lookingForPattern = false;
                }
            }
            else{
                /** Got the pattern, now just grab lines that are "non-zero". */
                if(line.length() > 0){
                    result[linesGrabbed++] = line;
                    if(linesGrabbed >= linesToGrab){ 
                        br.close();
                        return result; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
    return result;
    }
}
```

And here's how I use it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] result = CustomFileReader.getLines(
            new File("c:/stackoverflow/myFile.txt"), "012", 5);

    if(result != null){
        for(String line : result){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the results I got...

```
This is a line 012
This is a line 345
This is a line 678
This is a line 901
This is a line 234
```

In an attempt to get my answer more like what your code was going after, here is another version you could try...

I created another file with animals:

```
Some random line
Another ramdom line
*****
lion
tiger

bear
cow

pig
chicken
panda
```

Here is the Animal class with the methods (I think) you were trying to create.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Animals 
{

    /**
     * Based on your code, I'm guessing this method is meant to read all 
     * lines of a file containing a list of animals and return all the lines 
     * read from the file to whoever called this method...
     * I used a List instead of an array since you don't have to know how 
     * many lines are in the file ahead of time (you'd need to initialize an 
     * array, not a List.) I'll demonstrate how to access the List of 
     * Strings in the example.
     * @param filename pathname of the file. Ex. "c:/stackoverflow/myFile.txt"
     * or "c:\\stackoverflow\\myFile.txt"
     * @return List of Strings read from the file.
     */
    public static List<String> animalChoices (String filename) 
    {
        List<String> animalChoiceList = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader animals;
        try {
            animals = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            /* list returned with no entries. */
            return animalChoiceList;
        }

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = animals.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                animalChoiceList.add(line);
            } 
            animals.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        return animalChoiceList;
    }

    /**
     * Search a provided filename for a certain character string, add that
     * line to a String array, replace it with "ALERT!!! ", then add the
     * next (linesToGrab - 1) lines and add those to the array. Skip 
     * blank lines.
     * @param filename file path in String format "c:/folder/filename.txt"
     * @param searchCriteria ex. "*****" or "lion" or "1234"
     * @param linesToGrab total number of lines to grab
     * @return String array with the results. null if file not there.
     */
    public static String[] displayAnimals(String filename, 
            String searchCriteria, int linesToGrab)
    {
        /* initialize the array to linesToGet long. */
        String[] result = new String[linesToGrab];

        BufferedReader animals;
        try {
            animals = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.toString());
            /* return null if a reader could not be opened */
            return null;
        }

        int linesGrabbed = 0;
        boolean lookingForPattern = true;
        try {
            for(String line; (line = animals.readLine()) != null; )
            {
                if(lookingForPattern){
                    if(line.contains(searchCriteria)){
                        result[linesGrabbed++] = 
                                line.replace(searchCriteria, "ALERT!!! ");
                        lookingForPattern = false;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    /** Got the pattern, now just grab lines that are "non-zero". */
                    if(line.length() > 0){
                        result[linesGrabbed++] = line;
                        if(linesGrabbed >= linesToGrab){ 
                            animals.close();
                            return result; 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And here is how I use the Animal Class...

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.List;

public class StackOverflow {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = "c:/stackoverflow/animalFile.txt";

        List<String> animals = Animals.animalChoices(filename);
        System.out.println("All lines in the file:");
        for(String animal : animals){
            System.out.println(animal);
        }

        int linesToGet = 5;
        String searchCriteria = "*****";
        String[] result = 
                Animals.displayAnimals(filename, searchCriteria, linesToGet);
        System.out.println("\n\nOnly lines after the search criteria");
        for(String line : result){
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, the output when running the program...

```
All lines in the file:
Some random line
Another ramdom line
*****
lion
tiger

bear
cow

pig
chicken
panda


Only lines after the search criteria
ALERT!!! 
lion
tiger
bear
cow
```

Comment: Is there a way to run this based on a user input? For example if we wanted to look for numbers (in your case) it ran like you showed, or what if we wanted to look for letters (imagine the numbers posted were the respective letters of the alphabet)

Comment: The "numbers" were presented as a String, so you could replace the "012" with "e 0" and it would find the same line.

Comment: Regarding some of your syntax in the original attempt, I recommend you try using a program such as NetBeans IDE for example .  Your errors would be highlighted in red pointing out what you need to change, such as the "string" entries.

Comment: So with each animal there is a list of four lines after with details directly underneath it (this is uniform), I'll edit the question to show it better (sorry). I've been curious if its possible to read the n lines after a selected line. The ***** are for alerts that are supposed to be shown.